# Avoid unnecessary cursor after max length

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a custom code input UI , where the user needs to enter the code they receive on their mobile, i was using a package before but on IOS there is an autofill feature which didn't work because there were 5 different inputs instead of just one so i had to resort to custom solution.

I created an input with boxes as background image which works great the only issue is after max length is reached the cursor was pointing for another input , as a result it messed up the input field,let me show you my code

[image: Issue picture]

**HTML**

```
<input class="ios" type="tel" maxlength="5" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.ios{
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/AGzHqot.png");    
  width: 280px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 45px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight:500;
  font-size:20px;
  }
.ios:focus, .ios:focus, .ios:focus{}
  outline: none}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1at5buf/)

Please use the fiddle for replication of issue, enter upto 6 characters you'll see the issue

Comment: This is not really the recommended way to approach this problem. You're going to encounter all kinds of hurdles with this, especially if the Roboto font is unavailable and the browser has to use a different font. The 5 input solution may seem clunky and weird, but it's done that way for a reason. You'll genuinely have an easier time using the 5 input method than attempting to create your own homebrew solution that, quite frankly, is going to require a lot more effort to develop and maintain. I highly encourage you to reconsider this approach, for your own sake.

Comment: @B.Fleming I understand! thats what i mentioned to the team they said they had to make it work for IOS  whatever it may take so here I am,

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's work !!!

you can achieve your goal using small jQuery function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.ios').keyup(function (event) {
                var myLength = jQuery(this).val().length;

                if(myLength ==1){
                    jQuery(this).next('.ios').focus();
                }
            });  
        });
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.ios {border: 2px solid #efefef; border-radius: 5px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size:20px; text-align: center;}
.ios:focus, .ios:focus, .ios:focus{outline: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="ios" type="tel" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"/>
    <input class="ios" type="tel" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"/>
    <input class="ios" type="tel" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"/>
    <input class="ios" type="tel" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"/>
    <input class="ios" type="tel" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"/>
</div>
```